# route not found symfony5

Tags: php, symfony5

```
#[Route('/details/{id}', name: 'app_details')]
public function details(AutosRepository $autosRepository, Autos $id): Response
{

    $auto = $autosRepository->findBy(['id'=>$id]);
    return $this->render('auto/details.html.twig', [
        'controller_name' => 'AutoController',
        'autos' => $auto
    ]);
}


#[Route('/', name: 'app_home')]
public function index(AutosRepository $autosRepository): Response
{
   $autos = $autosRepository->findAll();
    return $this->render('auto/index.html.twig', [
        'controller_name' => 'AutoController',
        'autos' => $autos
    ]);
```

route to show id with finby - id
why does it not work?
its doesnt not use controller do i need to install symfony 5 again?
or how does it work